# VLookup Not working

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and have a `VLookup` set to find the row in a separate sheet (tab) based on a cell and return a link in the fourth column. I am using this formula:

`=IF((ISBLANK(C14)); ; VLOOKUP(C14; 'Sheet Names'!$A$2:$D$20; 4))`

There are two problems:

1. For some of the queries, it finds the row below the one it should return.
2. For some of the queries it shows `#N/A` even though the value is definitely in the column.

I cannot figure out a pattern to why some do not work.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HQERC4AP2O2j32IQ4VV2us4XPONJTqG0Tl2lOGj402Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's pretty easy to change the language to use for Google Sheets functions without changing the account language. Click on `Archivo > Configuración de la hoja de cálculo` then check the `Mostrar fórmulas en inglés` checkbox. Also bear in mind that you could post question in Spanish on [es.so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the right answer but when you need exact match always add a False in the last argument of the vlookup formula.

I never quite understood the differences of behavior with and without the last argument.

Anyway, Cell B15 is `=IF((ISBLANK(B14)); ; VLOOKUP(B14; 'Sheet Names'!$A$2:$D$20; 4))`

Just add the False like this `=IF((ISBLANK(B14)); ; VLOOKUP(B14; 'Sheet Names'!$A$2:$D$20; 4; False()))`

No more `#N/A`

Comment: Thanks! It didn't just get rid of the #N/A but it seems to also have fixed the situations where it was outputting the row below.